# C# AsyncCallback not needing Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am new to C# but not asynchronous programming. One thing I can't resolve in my own head though. If you use a thread or task in .Net and you want to update a Form control you have to use the Control.Invoke method but I have noticed lately when using BeginReceive on a socket I can update controls in the callback without explicitly invoking. I was under the impression that the callback would be executed on a different thread then the caller.

If this is not true how can I implement this in my own methods. I have a few branched executions to startup various services and have found I need to use invoke to display completion statuses. Worse yet I haven't found a way to invoke from the method doing the work which resides in another class but actually have to be within scope of the control and call the invoke on the control. I now write all my callbacks with a recursive check but if there is a way around it would be great

Thanks

Comment: Pretty hard to understand your question... Perhaps some code will help?

Comment: I don't believe you can rely on callback being called on the calling thread - this might be an implementation detail subject to change in later versions, as I don't see it specified in the docs. What is your actual question here, though? Is it for invoking without any Control reference? You might want to try something like invoking on something like System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[0]